# mySQL User permissions in information_schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema, user-permissions

I'm trying to find data from information_schema in mysql.

What I'm looking for is what permissions users have for tables.

So, say for example, I have two users - 'usr1' & 'usr2'. And four tables, tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4.

usr1 has access to tbl1 and tbl2 only, and usr2 has access to everything.

Where is this defined in information_schema? I can't seem to find it.

I've added some privileges to specific tables but nothing is shown in TABLE_PRIVILEGES so I can't tell if its supposed to be in there or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions data is stored in the `mysql` database: `columns_priv`, `db`, and `host` tables. information_schema contains the structural information about the tables, but not permissions.